# Emgu.CV.OCR not recognize a clear image. What could I do with the image to improve recognition?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to recognize a text in an image. I'm using Emgu.CV in C#.
I think the image is clear enough to get the text but I don't get 100%.(Attached two images
)

Can I do something with the image to obtain a better result?

I have used "eng" too but the result is the same.

```
Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract _ocr=new Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract(@"./tessdata", "spa", OcrEngineMode.Default);
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> original = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(fi.FullName);
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(105, 132, 50, 25);
original.ROI = rec;
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> crop = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(original.Width, original.Height);
CvInvoke.cvCopy(original, crop, IntPtr.Zero);
CvInvoke.Normalize(crop, crop, 0, 255, NormType.MinMax, DepthType.Default);
Emgu.CV.OCR.Pix pix = new Emgu.CV.OCR.Pix(crop.Mat);        
_ocr.SetImage(pix);
_ocr.Recognize();
var words = _ocr.GetCharacters();
```

[image: 1]

Get "AS000"

[image: 2]

Get "AO800"

Answer (score 0):

I try this

```
                Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract _ocr = new                                                                                 
                 Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract(@"./tessdata", "spa", OcrEngineMode.LstmOnly);
                 _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
                _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", "6");
                Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> original = new                     Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(fi.FullName);
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(105, 132, 100, 25);
                original.ROI = rec;
                Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> crop = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(original.Width, original.Height);
                CvInvoke.cvCopy(original, crop, IntPtr.Zero);
               

                Mat gray = new Mat();
                gray = crop.Mat;
                CvInvoke.CvtColor(crop, crop, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

                CvInvoke.Resize(crop, crop, new Size(crop.Cols*10, crop.Rows*10)); //for DPI

                CvInvoke.Threshold(crop, crop, 0, 255, ThresholdType.Binary | ThresholdType.Otsu); //for Binarize
            CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(crop, crop, new Size(1, 1), 0);



                Emgu.CV.OCR.Pix pix = new Emgu.CV.OCR.Pix(crop.Mat);
            
                _ocr.SetImage(pix);
                _ocr.Recognize();
```

The result is better but not 100%.